# Django Project created in Eclipse (PyDev) runs out of command line, not out of Eclipse

Tags: python, django, eclipse

I have created a Django Project in Eclipse. When I run manage.py from the commad line, it runs just fine, but when I run manage.py in Eclipse I get the Error Message below. The Project lives in an virtual environment that is stored at "C:\Users\Johanna\Envs\myproject\Scripts\python.exe".

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Johanna\workspace\Hide and Seek Game\manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Johanna\Envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Johanna\Envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 302, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "C:\Users\Johanna\Envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 55, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Users\Johanna\Envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 43, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Users\Johanna\Envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 99, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "C:\Users\Johanna\Envs\myproject\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 944, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 956, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'Hide and Seek Game'
```

I am happy for suggestions why this is the case.

Comment: Have you configured Eclipse to use python interpreter from your virtualenv?

Comment: yes, in the error messages you can see, that it is using django inside of the virtualeenv. (I have also tried running it outside the virtualenv - doesn't work either..)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by going to the project properties -> PyDev Django and setting the Django settings module.
[image]